# Looking for science fiction short stories by programmers

Tags: story-identification, computers

This was a collection of stories by software geeks, I believe.  Two key stories included:

- A supercomputer used to solve the problem of tornadoes
- An explorer who gave up his lunch while being thrown off a cliff, which saved his life

You'd probably have to have the book to get the references but... can't give the ending away.

Comment: You really need to include the ending if you remember. You can put it in spoiler tags (start the paragraph with `>!` )

Comment: Any other information is helpful too - when did you read it, what did the cover look like, how long was the book, etc

Answer (score 15):

Searching 'tornado' in ISFDB came up with a possibility:

Infinite Loop: Stories About the Future by the People Creating It : Software Development's Own Anthology of Science Fiction (1994), ed. by Larry Constantine

[Table of Contents from ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?18232)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I edited *Infinite Loop*. All the stories were by people associated with computer software, mostly programmers. (Out of print but used copies are still available.) Some of those stories, along with the rest of my own short stories, are compiled in [Requisite Variety](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0984377239) (Gesher Press, 2011).

Comment: So is this the collection the poster is looking for? Are there two stories in the book as described?

Answer (score 4):

Both of the current answers suggest *Infinite Loop* as the correct book.

The tornado story in *Infinite Loop* is titled "STORMY vs. the Tornadoes" which is available [online here](http://www.duntemann.com/stormy.htm) (~800 words)

It is about a National Weather Service supercomputer which was told to reduce US tornado fatalities, and is given authorization to spend up to $2,000 a transaction without human approval, and it spent $21 million dollars... in 18,000 transactions.  A Senator investigates.

```
"A supercomputer"
```

> that computer program of yours

```
 "used to solve the problem of tornadoes"
```

> STORMY's answer was immediate:
>
> TO KEEP TORNADOES FROM KILLING PEOPLE.